# Spring Auto Create Properties File

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

I have a simple class to represent property file using `@PropertySource` like so

```
@Component
@PropertySource(value = "file:${user.home}/.cooperp/app-conf.properties")
public class ApplicationProperties {
    @Value("${mysql-location}")
    private String mysqlLocation;

    public String getMysqlLocation() {
        return mysqlLocation;
    }

    public void setMysqlLocation(String mysqlLocation) {
       this.mysqlLocation = mysqlLocation;
    }
}
```

I know if file is not found one can add `ignoreResourceNotFound = true` which will make spring to ignore its absence and startup the application.

I would like spring to **create the file** it not found, not ignore or throw exception.

Comment: You will need to write code for that, that is not the task/function of `@PropertySource`.

Comment: Where, is it in main method?

Comment: Why do you want to do this ?

Comment: I would like the file and properties to be present when needed with default values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually we keep the properties file withing the project directory. But if your project requires the properties outside then you can check if the file exists in SpringBootApplication class. If it doesen't, then you can create the properties file there. Code example :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringDocBotApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("EXPECTED PATH"); 

        try{
            if(!file.exists()){
                // create propeties file add properties
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
         //HANDLE EXCEPTION
        }
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDocBotApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```